# Client.DownloadString issue

Tags: c#, winforms

The code is supposed to read the raw Pastebin get its link and download it:

```
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        var client = new WebClient();
        string SourceDir = @"./";
        string SourceZip = @"./FILE";
        string Download = client.DownloadString("PastebinLink");
        client.DownloadFile(Download, @"File");
        ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(SourceZip, SourceDir);
        System.IO.File.Delete(SourceZip);
        Process.Start(@"./FILE");
```

When I debugged it responded with this

> System.Net.WebException: 'The Remote Server Returned An Error:
> (302) Found.

Is there a fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you look up what [the HTTP 302 code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/302) means?

> The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) 302 Found redirect status response code indicates that the resource requested has been temporarily moved to the URL given by the `Location` header. A browser redirects to this page...

The response includes a `Location` header directing you to where the resource is.  You'll need to read that header and follow that URL.

Since this throws an exception (I personally don't think it *should*, but it looks like it does according to your description) then you'll need to wrap it in a try/catch to handle this.  Structurally this might look something like:

```
string Download = "";
try
{
    Download = client.DownloadString("PastebinLink");
}
catch (WebException ex)
{
    // See if the response contains a Location header
    string newLink = ex.Response?.Headers.Get("Location");
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(newLink))
    {
        // If the response contained a Location header, use it
        Download = client.DownloadString(newLink);
    }
    else
    {
        // The error response didn't contain a Location header
        // so let the exception continue up the stack
        throw;
    }
}

if (Download == "")
{
    // The attempt failed, handle the problem here
}

// The attempt succeeded, continue with your logic here
```